# How to create a method with 2 arrays as parameters?

Tags: java, netbeans

How can I pass 2 predefined arrays as parameters to a method, here is my tried code:

```
   public class MergeArrays {
    public int array1[] = new int[5];
    public int array2[] = new int[5];
    private int[] mergeArray(array1,array2){

    }
}
```

Comment: `private int[] mergeArray(int[] array1, int[] array2)` ?

Comment: You don't need to pass them, you just use them directly within your method

Comment: you just forgot that you need to declare the type of your parameters

Comment: @musefan unless of course it's supposed to be re-usable

Comment: @Berger you are right, I totally forgot about initializing, if you want to post the answer so i can upvote

Comment: @AlbertoMartínez : I consider it more like a typo-related question, so it won't need a regular answer :) . Feel free to accept the other answer though.

Comment: @Stultuske: Yeah but the question doesn't say how to define a method, it says how to pass 2 **pre-defined** arrays as parameters, and based on the fact the params have the same name as the fields, then it would suggest OP wants to use those values

Comment: @musefan the question says one thing, the title another.

Comment: @musefan I would like to see your answer too, so I can know if there is another way if the arrays are already defined

Comment: @Stultuske: Yeah I guess it does

Comment: @AlbertoMartínez: Well you can't have 2 different answers to 1 question... decide which one your question is

Comment: @musefan my doubts are already solved, thanks to all of you for your time :)

Answer (score 3):

To answer your specific question "How can I pass 2 predefined arrays as parameters to a method", you need to specify the types of the parameters in your method:

```
private int[] mergeArray(int[] array1, int[] array2)
```

Then you can call it with:

```
mergeArray(array1, array2);
```

A bigger example:

```
public class MergeArrays {

    public int array1[] = new int[5];
    public int array2[] = new int[5];

    private int[] mergeArray(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
        // TODO
    }


    public static void main(String... args) {

        MergeArrays merger = new MergeArrays();
        merger.array1[0] = 18;
        merger.array1[1] = 28;
        merger.array2[0] = 991;
        // etc.

        int[] mergedArray = merger.mergeArray(array1, array2);
        // TODO
    }
}
```

It's worth mentioning this is not great code.

The names of the parameters in the method clash with (and conceal) the names of the instance variables. This may be confusing and if you want to access the instance variables from within the method you'll have to prefix them with `this.`

In general in object-oriented programs, you want to hide internal data representations like the arrays, rather than making them public. For example, perhaps later you will want to use an `ArrayList` instead. If you make the fields public then other classes may refer to them and so changes will cause knock-on effects in the code base.

Your `mergeArray` method would be better named `merge` or `mergeArrays` (plural) and should be `static` unless it depends on the internal state of the class.

Comment: @musefan this is exactly what the OP asked for.

Comment: If think what he means is have the arrays instantiated using the args or something like that....